# c# gomoku game label array

Tags: c#, arrays, logic, gomoku

I am trying to make a simple five in a row (gomoku) game for two players using windows forms and c#. I put a picturebox with a picture and stretched it out on the form. Now I want to put labels at all the intersections on the picture board so a user can click them and change their background color to black or white.

1. How can I make the labels created clickable on the form?

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       int labelCount = 0;
       int iteration = 0;

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           Label[] board = new Label[361];

           for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
           {
               board[i] = new Label
               {
                   Name = "label" + i,
                   Height = 55,
                   Width = 55,
                   MinimumSize = new Size(55, 55),
                   Text = "label " + i
               };
           }

           int x = 0;
           int y = 0;

           foreach (var Label in board)
           {
               if (x >= 580)
               {
                   x = 0;
                   y = y + Label.Height + 55;
               }

               Label.Location = new Point(x, y);
               this.Controls.Add(Label);
               x += Label.Width;
           }        
       }
   }
   ```
2. Should I make a one-dimensional [361] or two-dimensional array`[{A,1}, {A,2}....{D,1}]` to easily check for a winner? How can I connect it to the created labels so the array data corresponds to the objects on the board?

Answer (score 0):

Well Sorry If don`t understand your question. For the Q.1 to add 361 labels you can try the code below. I hope it will help you.

```
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    private Label[] moku =  new Label[361];

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
            {
                moku[i] = new Label();
                moku[i].Parent = pictureBox1;//make the picturebox parent
                moku[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
                moku[i].Text = "O";
                moku[i].Name = "moku" + i;
                moku[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                pictureBox1.Controls.Add(moku[i]);
                y += 55;
                if (y >= 361) { x += 55; y = 0; x+=55; }
            }
        }catch(Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a 2D array because it's easier if you want to check the surrounding boxes.

**Form design:**

[image]

**Full source:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public enum Player
    {
        Empty = 0,
        White,
        Black
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // initialize board of 5x5
        private Player[,] board = new Player[5, 5];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawBoard();
        }

        private void DrawBoard()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= board.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j <= board.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                {
                    // for name and text
                    var name = string.Format("{0}, {1}", i, j);

                    var label = new Label()
                    {
                        Name = name, // name of label
                        Size = new Size(55, 55),
                        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        Location = new Point(i * 55, j * 55), // location depends on iteration
                        Text = name
                    };

                    label.Click += ClickLabel; // subscribe the Click event handler

                    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label); // add label to a container
                }
            }
        }

        // this event handler will handle all the labels click event
        private void ClickLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label = (Label)sender; // this is the label that you click
            var x = Convert.ToInt32(label.Name.Split(',')[0]);
            var y = Convert.ToInt32(label.Name.Split(',')[1]);

            // change the color
            if (radPlayerBlack.Checked)
            {
                // Player Black
                label.ForeColor = Color.White;
                label.BackColor = Color.Black;
                board[x, y] = Player.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                // Player White
                label.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                label.BackColor = Color.White;
                board[x, y] = Player.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the value of the 2D array for black or white. Here's the value when I QuickWatch it in Visual Studio.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to add event handler to your labels, I have supplied it in my solution.